# recover deletion from "Git init folder"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, init

I had a folder with ROR code lets call it "subfolder" under main folder call it "mainfolder"
I made a mistake and ran "git init subfolder" from the "main folder" 
That command deleted most of the code there except the tmp, log and empty app directory

I further pulled from the git remote from the subfolder without realizing that the files got deleted

then touch readme

then add . then commit -m "first commit" that's when I got files a message like

master 34f2e90] first commit
 42 files changed, 84328 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 README
 create mode 100644 log/development.log
 create mode 100644 tmp/cache/assets/C7A/6A0/sprockets%2F442a717507a3dde80b7d59671208324c
 create mode 100644 tmp/cache/assets/C9F/560/sprockets%2F8e5a9738e9bc15478e026d98335454f9
 create mode 100644 tmp/cache/assets/CBF/380/sprockets%2F4f4c8476962893413bc66624ebedc372

Then

git push origin master

Counting objects: 127, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (85/85), done.
Writing objects: 100% (126/126), 389.53 KiB, done.
Total 126 (delta 14), reused 0 (delta 0)

Is there any way to recover those deleted files?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git init does not delete files.  It only adds a .git directory.

You must have accidentally run another command to delete those files.  Can you show the output of your shell "history" command for the commands surrounding this event?

Comment: Git init still didn't delete your files.  Those messages are normal and simply mean that you added stuff and committed.  I've tried several different scenarios to duplicate your problem and cannot.  Your shell's history command should show us exactly the commands you ran.  Show us that and we might be able to help, though it's likely the files are gone unless you want to use an undelete utility to attempt to recover them.